# PyCharm hotkey for "console" in debug mode

Tags: pycharm

I like to operate my computer as much as possible avoiding having to use a mouse. PyCharm makes this very easy, just this one thing I cannot figure out: When I Debug my code, is there a hot key to "click" on the console?

[image]